# How to make a horizontal merge in SSRS Dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc

I am creating a report that generates a timeline calendar. I managed to make it work but now I'm stuck with the new problem. I don't know how to merge the cell column with the same year value dynamically. I have no idea how to do this. I am no expert when creating reports. But I think it's very simple to others. Please help.

[image: Here's the screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You don't merge the cells in order to do that.

You have to create a (parent of month) column group (in tablix or matrix) and set the Year as the group value.

[image]

[image]